# How to write bash script or automate the open vi and edit document?

Tags: linux, shell-script

I'd like to write a bash script that essentially automates this process:

```
vi filename.sh
```

(open "filename.sh" using vi)

add the following 2 lines:

```
export GRADLE_HOME=/opt/gradle/gradle-5.2.1
export PATH=${GRADLE_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

and save those changes

```
:wq!
```

Basically I want to add these in jenkins file for automation

Comment: Where do you want to add those lines? At the beginning, at the end, at a specific position? Edit your question to include this. This is *not* a job for `vi`.

Comment: I am creating a new file and adding these lines

Comment: Can't Jenkins transfer files? Why not create that file once and transfer it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vi` is by definition a visual editor.

In this case it's probably better to use some other means.

If you only want to append those lines, do something like:

```
cat >> filename.sh <<'EOF'
export GRADLE_HOME=/opt/gradle/gradle-5.2.1
export PATH=${GRADLE_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
EOF
```

This will also work if the file doesn't exist yet.

If you want those lines added at the beginning, you can use `ed` which is a line-oriented editor:

```
ed filename.sh <<'EOF'
1i
export GRADLE_HOME=/opt/gradle/gradle-5.2.1
export PATH=${GRADLE_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
.
w
q
EOF
```

This instructs `ed` to insert lines at line 1; the solitary dot `.` on the line indicates the end of input, so insertion stops there. Finally the file is written (`w`) and the edit session quitted (`q`).

If you insist on using `ed` even if the file doesn't exist yet (in which case I would use the `cat` example above), you can use this:

```
ed filename.sh <<'EOF'
i
export GRADLE_HOME=/opt/gradle/gradle-5.2.1
export PATH=${GRADLE_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
.
w filename.sh
q
EOF
```

The main difference is that you don't pass a line number with the `i` insert command, as there are no lines yet; and you pass a filename to the `w` write command which is the new file.

`sed` can also be used, but for such tasks I find `ed` easier to use (and to read what's happening).

Comment: after doing ed getting No such file or directory error:

[root@fcired67 ~]# ed /etc/s1.sh <<'EOF'
> 1i
> export GRADLE_HOME=/opt/gradle/gradle-5.2.1
> export PATH=${GRADLE_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
> .
> w
> q
> EOF
/etc/s1.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: That sounds like the file `/etc/s1.sh` does not exist. The file needs to exist before `ed` can edit it.

Comment: yes, first have to create that file then needs to add the lines
so what changes should i add now to make it work?

Comment: I've edited my answer to handle the case where the file doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @wurtel you could have been even better IMHO if you cut your examples a bit down and concentrate on these three steps in OQ; 1)open file 2)operate data 3)write file OQ says automate, and you say visual editor etc. maybe it is a small algorithm where a filetest and a sed line is needed --- more of: it depends: on A, B and C. Then you have solutions X, Y, Z, e.g. Y:

Comment: `ed` can create files.  It is a text editor, after all.  The problem with your first `ed` example is that you have `1` and `i` on one line as one command.  if you them them on separate lines, then the `1` would move to the first line on an existing file, or be a non-fatal error on new files.  the `i` would insert at the beginning of the file either way.   e.g. try `printf '%s\n' 1 i line1 line2 . w q | ed does-not-exist.txt`

Comment: @rastafile do you even make sense to yourself?

Comment: @cas I just post an answer: a three-quarter liner. `cat twoline-file >>filename.sh`

Answer (score 1):

Automated scripting can be done using `ed`

like 
`ed < edit.sed filename.pdf`

For more, you can visit [**this**](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) tutorial.

Comment: Also, I found a similar question [**Here**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/848275/how-to-write-bash-script-to-open-vi-and-edit-document) on **askUbuntu**

Comment: For inserting at a _specific_ line that is fine. `sed` is a tool for that. But from what we know, appending at the end is enough. Two lines (in a file, I propose) and a file: not so difficult to _concatenate_ with `cat`, if not for that in-place problem, which can be solved with `>>` redirection.

Answer (score 0):

I would also do it the way @wurtel is suggesting, but if
for some reason you really want to do it with **vi**, add the following to your **$HOME/.vimrc file**:

```
function AddVars()
    let line1 = "export GRADLE_HOME=/opt/gradle/gradle-5.2.1"
    let line2 = "export PATH=${GRADLE_HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
    call append(line('$'), line1)
    call append(line('$'), line2)
    write
    exit
endf
```

And then call *vi* with using the -c option like this:
`vi filename.sh -c "call AddVars()"`

Comment: If you prefer to add the lines at the beginning of the file, change  `call append(line('$'), line1)` with `call append(line('1'), line2)` and `call append(line('$'), line2)` with `call append(line('$'), line1)`

Comment: you append at the end; OQ says "add" (and he is in vi). See comment at wurtel. And of course you could aliias that long vi command further.

Comment: Thank you @rastafile, good point

Comment: _just right now_ I posted a answer myself!. Thx to cas, see his bark. I like your vim function a lot, but not for this Q. Save it for smth more complex.